# Getting NHibernate error Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm having some issues with a query of a table that includes a space in it's name

If i write a sql-query it works fine, ie SELECT * FROM [product groups], but when using NHibernate CreateQuery everything breaks

```
using (ISession session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM [product groups]");
    IList<ProductGroups> results = query.List<ProductGroups>();
}
```

Will generate the error

> Exception of type 'Antlr.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown.
>   near line 1, column 5    at
>
> > NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.ErrorCounter.ThrowQueryException()    at
> >      NHibernate.Hql.Ast.ANTLR.HqlParseEngine.Parse()
> >      ...

If I use a CreateSQLQuery it works

```
ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT ID, Title, [Available as develop] FROM [product groups]").AddEntity(typeof(ProductGroups));
IList<ProductGroups> results = query.List<ProductGroups>();
```

The mapping file looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true">
  <class name="ListModels.ProductGroups, ListModels" lazy="true" table="Product groups">
    <id name="ID">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="Title" />
    <property name="AvailableAsDevelopmentLicense" column="Available as develop" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Why would not CreateQuery work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `CreateQuery()`, described here: [9.3.2. The IQuery interface](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-queryinterface), is the way how to query your Entities with [14. HQL: The Hibernate Query Language](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#queryhql).

I.e. you have to use your **domain** model names `ProductGroups`  instead of the *table* name `[product groups]`

```
//IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM [product groups]");
IQuery query = session.CreateQuery("FROM ListModels.ProductGroups as pg");
```

Comment: This is perfectly correct, I also had to set the table parameter in the class in the hbm file, thanks.